# Can't use input pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm very new at PL/SQL so forgive me if the solution is obvious. I'm trying to have the user input some variables, but I can't use those variables at all. Here's a sample of the code:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
ACCEPT MaxRecords INTEGER := PROMPT 'Enter the number of records to input:';
DECLARE
    MaxRecords INTEGER;
BEGIN
    IF MaxRecords > 1000 THEN
        MaxRecords := 1000;
        dbms_output.put_line('You cannot input more than 1,000 records.');
    END IF;
    dbms_output.put_line('Number of records to input: ' || MaxRecords);
END;
```

All I get out is "Number of records to input: " no matter what I put in MaxRecords. And if the number is greater than 1000, it doesn't go through the IF statement

Comment: Assuming your eventual goal is to get the client to input up to 1000 values (rather than just accepting a single value and writing a single line of output), you realistically can't.  PL/SQL runs on the server so you cannot realistically embed SQL*Plus commands like `ACCEPT` in a PL/SQL loop.  It is (barely) possible to do some sort of looping in SQL*Plus but it's hideously painful and should be avoided like the plague.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
ACCEPT MaxRec INTEGER := PROMPT 'Enter the number of records to input:';
DECLARE
    MaxRecords INTEGER:=&MaxRec;
BEGIN
    IF MaxRecords > 1000 THEN
        MaxRecords := 1000;
        dbms_output.put_line('You cannot input more than 1,000 records.');
    END IF;
    dbms_output.put_line('Number of records to input: ' || MaxRecords);
END;
```

The & forces sql to substitute MaxRec

SQLPLUS ACCEPT example:

```
SQL> accept foo
1
SQL> select &foo from dual;
old   1: select &foo from dual
new   1: select 1 from dual
```

Comment: Ok, that seems to work. But how come I have to use a different variable?

Comment: The first one is not really a PL/SQL variable, but you can try using the same name.  What you gain I do not understand.  Readability?

Comment: I don't understand what that means "not really a PL/SQL variable". Isn't it all PL/SQL?

Comment: accept is sqlplus syntax.  the DECLARE ...BEGIN ... END part is PL/SQL

Comment: I added a pure sqlplus version to the post.